# How to test my data against an specific normal distribution?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, nonparametric, matlab

I need to test my data to see if it follows a normal distribution with specific mean and std like N~(mu, std) I know that this can be done by  Kolmogorov-Smirnov test which has a function in both MATLAB and R but the default for these function is standard normal and I do not know how should I specify my mu and std in the function. If you can help me in any of these two softwares I will be thankful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ks.test` in `R` allows one to adjust the mean and sd of the distribution to be tested against. e.g.

```
x <- rnorm(1000, 4, 10)
ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean = 4, sd = 10)
```

Answer (score 13):

In R, you can just use the function `ks.test` with the following arguments:

```
ks.test(your_data, "pnorm", mean=test_mu, sd=test_sd)
```

Where `your_data` is your data vector, `test_mu` is the specific mean of the theoretical normal distribution and `test_sd` its standard deviation.

To inspect your data graphically, you can use the function `qqPlot` from the `car` package. Just use it with the following arguments:

```
qqPlot(your_data, "norm", mean=test_mu, sd=test_sd)
```

This produces a Q-Q plot with a comparison line and a 95% point-wise confidence envelope (as default).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

So don't use the default! As already noted, R lets you specify the population mean and standard deviation.

Here is how to do it in MATLAB or anything else that doesn't give you the option to specify:

*Standardize your variable by the population parameters:* $z_i = \frac{x_i-\mu_0}{\sigma_0}$

... and then test against standard normal.

(However, if those $\mu$ and $\sigma$ values come from a *sample*... don't do this!)

Comment: +1 for being the first to point out the important point that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ should not be estimates.